# Viewing your own documentation

Tags: packages, documentation, paclets

I am currently making a paclet, writing documentation for my package.

When writing documentation with the Documentation tools, it is displayed in an ``unfinished way".

How would it be possible to view it, in the same format we see documentation in the Wolfram Documentation centre. (On Mathematica 13.0).

I guess another question would be, is there a way to see the "raw" version of documentation in the wolfram centre instead?

Current format:
[image: Instead of This]

How I want to see it:

[image: Have this?]

Comment: Just to make sure, you need to build the documentation, you know that, right?

Comment: To answer your second question, no you can not see the raw Wolfram documentation, only the build documentation is shipped with the product. Some exceptions are for paclets that are shared publically. For example [OpenCascadeLink](https://github.com/WolframResearch/OpenCascadeLink)

Comment: @user21 Thank you. I did realize I need to build it, but I think I passed the paclet incorrectly into the documentation build function the first time. Thank you.
It just saves in a different build folder... I should be ashamed.

Comment: @MstislavKeldysh - this is a shame-free zone really